# Using Bootstrap and Javascript for a Toast function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using Bootstrap 4 in order to create Toasts, I'm currently making a JavaScript function in order to generate a toast.

I have attempted to create elements within the JS file, this didn't properly style it.

index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div>
            <div style="position: absolute; top: 50%; right: 50%">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" onclick="newToast('Test', 'Test2')">Example</button>
        </div>

        <div aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true" class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="min-height: 200px;">
            <div style="position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 5px;">

            <div class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" data-delay=3000 id="toast">
                <div class="toast-header">
                    <strong class="mr-auto" id="t-header">
                        Header
                    </strong>
                    <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="toast-body" id="t-body">
                    Body
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="toast.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

toast.js

```
function newToast(Header, Body) {
    var toast = {}
    toast.Header = Header
    toast.Body = Body
    toast.Hide = function() {
        // todo, hide
    }

    var header = document.getElementById("t-header")
    var body = document.getElementById("t-body")
    header.innerHTML = toast.Header
    body.innerHTML = toast.Body

    $('.toast').toast('show');
    return toast
}

let toast = newToast("Header Test", "Body Test")
```

Currently if you make a new toast while one is currently visible it will overwrite the visible one, it should stack however. Bootstrap automatically will stack your Toasts. I believe I need make an entirely new toast and then appendChild, this didn't work for me though.

Comment: do you wnat your toest well done or slightly brown ?

Comment: jk I would propose to add all the toast requests to an array and save them until you know the previous toast is finsihed (check the array in the hide function and display the next one if its not empty)

Comment: I don't want to wait for the toast to finish in order to send a new one, they should stack.

Comment: like stack on top of each other ?

Comment: Yes. Bootstrap automatically does that for you, I just need help generating a Toast and putting it in HTML.

Comment: in this case instead of assignint the html to the header / vbody elements you need to create a new oen each time useful methods : DOMElement.appendChild() and DOMElement.cloneNode(true) this way you can keep using the html you already created

Comment: This almost works however now it's offset by a toast due to the cloned invisible one

Comment: how about setting the invisible one to style.position="fixed" and changing it back on the cloned ones

Comment: Yeah I did it, however due to it being a node I'm not entirely sure I can modify the text of the Header and the Body?

Comment: so im not entirely sure how the toast.HEader and Body is setup but you can set .textContent="text" for any DOMNode as well you might need to find the correct DOM element in the header /body though to set it on

Comment: Yeah I know about that but I need to get the header node first.. You can see that in the HTML code I gave.

Comment: I tohugh something like this : `var header = document.getElementById("t-header");let headerCopy=header.cloneNode(true);headerCopy.textContent="newTExt" ` (or maybe even headerCopy.innerHTML=toast.HEader ; kinda unneccesary to load it from DOM beforehand in this case though)

Comment: That would work if I was copying the Header, I'm copying the entire toast container.

Comment: then do copiedContainer.getElementById("t-header")  then its the same as before

Comment: getElemetByID() isn't a function for ```var toastClone = document.getElementById("toastClone").cloneNode(true)```

Comment: oh interesting but you can still do .getElementsByClassName('toast-header')[0]

Comment: You've read [the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/toasts/)? It has examples that show multiple toasts.

Answer (score 0):

Add data-autohide="false"

```
<div class="toast" data-autohide="false" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" data-delay=3000 id="toast">
```

Toast has to be initialized with jQuery:

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".toast").toast("show");
      });
    </script>
```